# copy all contents from listbox (variable rows, constant columns) to to table at button click (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform where the user will populate a listbox from various other form controls (textboxes, comboboxes, etc). There are 8 columns that will be populated for each data entry. The idea is that the user will input data entries (which might be sub-entries in the same category of entries, hence the desired functionality of being able to review the entire batch (or *category*) of entries together in a listbox), review the inputs, and if it checks out, click a button in order to submit the data to a table (which is the basis for the data process mode, to spit out charts, etc based on the input data batches).

So I would like to program the following:
- Code that finds the next empty row in the main table, and copies the entire content of the Listbox to exch respective cell in the table from this point. Thus the entry will be 8 columns (column A-H) and X rows each time.

I have tried a number of different codes adapted from around the web, but keep getting errors or being only able to copy the first entry.

This is the last code sample I tried:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

Dim LastRow As Range
Dim ProjectsTable As ListObject
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects").ListRows.Add

'Enter data from form into our new row
Set ProjectsTable = Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects")
Set LastRow = ProjectsTable.ListRows(ProjectsTable.ListRows.Count).Range

With Sheets("Project data")
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    .Cells(LastRow, 1) = ListBox1.Column(i, 0)
    .Cells(LastRow, 2) = ListBox1.Column(i, 1)
    .Cells(LastRow, 3) = ListBox1.Column(i, 2)
    .Cells(LastRow, 4) = ListBox1.Column(i, 3)
    .Cells(LastRow, 5) = ListBox1.Column(i, 4)
    .Cells(LastRow, 6) = ListBox1.Column(i, 5)
    .Cells(LastRow, 7) = ListBox1.Column(i, 6)
    .Cells(LastRow, 8) = ListBox1.Column(i, 7)
Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Could anyone help me towards a solution? I'd be grateful for any pointers.

SOLUTION:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

Dim ProjectsTable As ListObject
Dim LastRow As Range

Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects").ListRows.Add

'Enter data from form into our new row
Set ProjectsTable = Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects")
Set LastRow = ProjectsTable.ListRows(ProjectsTable.ListRows.Count).Range

LastRow.Resize(ListBox1.ListCount, ListBox1.ColumnCount).Value = ListBox1.List

End Sub
```

Credit goes to @Nathan_Sav . Many thanks!

Comment: The contents are held in an array `.list` you could try something based on that `range("a1:a10")=arr(1 to 10)`

Comment: Is LastRow a named range or a number??? it is already a range, so I  would imagine `lastrow.resize(y,x)`.   what line errors?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav LastRow is supposed to be the first blank row found in the data table. This is a cumulative data table (with all the entry batches) thus it will be a new row further down each time (not replacing old content). 

It's the `Sheets("Project data").Range("LastRow").Resize(ListBox1.ListCount, ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1).Value = ListBox1.List` line that errs. Hope this helps.

Comment: see my comment, use lastrow as it's a range, so use `lastrow.cells(1,1).resize`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav seems to work now, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
Range("a1").Resize(Me.lstTabsAvailable.ListCount, Me.lstTabsAvailable.ColumnCount).Value = Me.lstTabsAvailable.List
```

Comment: Hello Nathan_Sav

Many thanks for your comment. So "lstTabsAvailable" represents the listbox I presume? 
I will need to put this under something like a 'With' *relevant sheet* type of code?

Thanks!

Comment: yep, can you finish it, afternoon quiz :)

Comment: I amended and tried as following:
`Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

Dim ProjectsTable As ListObject
Dim LastRow As Range

Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects").ListRows.Add

'Enter data from form into our new row
Set ProjectsTable = Sheets("Project data").ListObjects("Projects")
Set LastRow = ProjectsTable.ListRows(ProjectsTable.ListRows.Count).Range

Sheets("Project data").Range("LastRow").Resize(ListBox1.ListCount, ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1).Value = ListBox1.List

End Sub`
Unfortunately get `application defined or object defined error`
Any tips on this one? @Nathan_Sav

Comment: That one came out too messy, will post in OP instead :)